# PHP assoc array sorting JSON data by category and numerical key extention

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm generating JSON from a Wordpress database and so far have the following JSON chunk I need to sort in PHP. It's messy but the database was setup that way by the plugin. 
It's going to be a food menu (dummy data at the moment) and each item has a category such as mains, desserts.  Each numerical `meta_key` increment is a different item on the menu that has been added by the client and the title, desc, image and price are connected this way.

The data is grouped by post id and then I need to group all the mains together, followed by the desserts etc. The data is a little jumbled up as each menu item has an incremental numerical `meta_key` which is dynamic by the end user based on how many items they have added.

The JSON is as follows and afterwards I'll write what I need to achieve if you can help.

```
[
    {
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_cat_0",
    "meta_value": "Mains"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_cat_1",
    "meta_value": "Mains"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_cat_2",
    "meta_value": "Mains"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_cat_3",
    "meta_value": "Desserts"
},
 {  "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_d_image_id_0",
    "meta_value": "2246"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_d_price_0",
    "meta_value": "12233"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_d_title_0",
    "meta_value": "dia title boxee"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_description_0",
    "meta_value": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_description_1",
    "meta_value": "Other"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_description_2",
    "meta_value": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_description_3",
    "meta_value": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_image_id_0",
    "meta_value": "2256"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_image_id_1",
    "meta_value": "2269"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_image_id_2",
    "meta_value": "2256"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_image_id_3",
    "meta_value": "2256"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_order_0",
    "meta_value": ""
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_order_1",
    "meta_value": ""
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_order_2",
    "meta_value": ""
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_order_3",
    "meta_value": ""
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_price_0",
    "meta_value": "12.99"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_price_1",
    "meta_value": "14.99"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_price_2",
    "meta_value": "1.99"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_price_3",
    "meta_value": "3.85"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_title_0",
    "meta_value": "Mains 1"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_title_1",
    "meta_value": "Mains 2"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_title_2",
    "meta_value": "Mains 3"
},
{
    "post_id": 2202,
    "meta_key": "_menu_title_3",
    "meta_value": "Dessert 1"
}
]
```

What I would like to achieve :

```
[
     "Mains" {
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_0": "Food title",
            "_menu_description_0": "food desc",
            "_menu_price_0": "food price",
            "_menu_image_id_0": "url"
          },
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_1": "Food title",
            "_menu_description_1": "food desc",
            "_menu_price_1": "food price",
            "_menu_image_id_1": "url"
          },
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_2": "Food title",
            "_menu_description_2": "food desc",
            "_menu_price_2": "food price",
            "_menu_image_id_2": "url"
          },

     }

     "Desserts" {
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_0": "dessert title",
            "_menu_description_0": "des food desc",
            "_menu_price_0": "des food price",
            "_menu_image_id_0": "url"
          },
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_1": "Food title",
            "_menu_description_1": "food desc",
            "_menu_price_1": "food price",
            "_menu_image_id_1": "url"
          },
          {
            "post_id": 2202,
            "_menu_title_2": "Food title",
            "_menu_description_2": "food desc",
            "_menu_price_2": "food price",
            "_menu_image_id_2": "url"
          },

     }

]
```

And so on changing with a new category array each time it loops in PHP.  The PHP code to generate the existing JSON is below:

```
    $list = array();
    $info5 = $q->doQuery("SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ? AND meta_key LIKE '_menu_%'", array($postID));
        foreach($info5 as $row){
                 array_push($list,$row);
        } 
                asort($list);

            foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
                array_push($json,$key = $val);
            }


echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your original json entries are missing references to mains or desserts for most of the entries.  How would you know which ones to match to which category?

Comment: I was trying to match the meta keys numerically and group them under the category from the _menu_cat_$i somehow.

Comment: Can you use WP_Query() to get all the information for the custom post type of 'menu-items' and then get_post_meta() to get all the extra information.  That way, you can build out the array of arrays all in PHP, pass as json in a finished format.  I use PODs to build simple custom post types.  You can also do it in the functions.php file https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wanted to post this as maybe it could help someone else with a similar problem in the future.  Finally figured it out with a coding buddy Adam Creighton who used a great preg_replace to get the results ordered correctly.

```
if($requestType==5){
    $info5 = $q->doQuery("SELECT meta_key,meta_value from wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ? AND meta_key LIKE '_menu_%'", array($what));
sort($info5);
    $menu = array();
        $items = array();
        foreach($info5 as $row){
            $int = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $row["meta_key"]);
            $items[$int][$row["meta_key"]] = $row["meta_value"];
            if(strpos('_menu_cat_', $row["meta_key"]) === true){
                $menu[$row["meta_value"]] = array();
            }
        }

        foreach($items as $key => $value){
            $int = count($menu[$value["_menu_cat_".$key]]);
            $menu[$value["_menu_cat_".$key]][$int] = $value;
        }

    $json=$menu;
}

//BIG FILESIZE BUT COSMETIC FOR CHECKING ONLINE PAGE
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Outputs the following from the original code.

```
{
    "Mains": [
        {
        "_menu_cat_0": "Mains",
        "_menu_description_0": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_0": "2256",
        "_menu_order_0": "",
        "_menu_price_0": "12.99",
        "_menu_title_0": "Mains 1"
    },
    {
        "_menu_cat_1": "Mains",
        "_menu_description_1": "Other",
        "_menu_image_id_1": "2269",
        "_menu_order_1": "",
        "_menu_price_1": "14.99",
        "_menu_title_1": "Mains 2"
    },
    {
        "_menu_cat_2": "Mains",
        "_menu_description_2": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_2": "2256",
        "_menu_order_2": "",
        "_menu_price_2": "1.99",
        "_menu_title_2": "Mains 3"
    },
    {
        "_menu_cat_4": "Mains",
        "_menu_description_4": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_4": "2256",
        "_menu_order_4": "",
        "_menu_price_4": "12.99",
        "_menu_title_4": "Mains again"
    }
],
"Desserts": [
    {
        "_menu_cat_3": "Desserts",
        "_menu_description_3": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_3": "2256",
        "_menu_order_3": "",
        "_menu_price_3": "3.85",
        "_menu_title_3": "Dessert 1"
    }
],
"Tapas": [
    {
        "_menu_cat_5": "Tapas",
        "_menu_description_5": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_5": "2256",
        "_menu_order_5": "",
        "_menu_price_5": "12.99",
        "_menu_title_5": "Tapas 1"
    },
    {
        "_menu_cat_6": "Tapas",
        "_menu_description_6": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_6": "2256",
        "_menu_order_6": "",
        "_menu_price_6": "12.99",
        "_menu_title_6": "Tapas 2"
    },
    {
        "_menu_cat_7": "Tapas",
        "_menu_description_7": "With a choice of either; Mature cheddar, American cheese, Red Leicester or Applewood smoked cheddar. Served with our original HBC burger relish, mayo, lettuce, tomato & red onion",
        "_menu_image_id_7": "2256",
        "_menu_order_7": "",
        "_menu_price_7": "12.99",
        "_menu_title_7": "Tapas 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the array and build a associated array based on the key.

```
//assuming $list is what you had posted above
//and $sort is the final
$sort = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($list);$i++){
  if(!isset($sort[$list[$i]['meta_value']]) $sort[$list[$i]['meta_value']] = [];
  $sort[$list[$i]['meta_value']].push($list[i]);
}
```

Please consider the above code just starter code to point the right way there might be some typos.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I've been outputting all sorts of odd combinations all day and needed some clarity from someone. I'll get going again on it again now :)